# How can I filter on a partitioned timestamp field dynamically?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, partitioning

I have a table partitioned on insert_datetime.

The below query results in 250GB processed.

```
select *
from [table]
```

If I do the below, it is reduced to 500MB. This is the desired behavior, but ideally I would not need to hard code a timestamp.

```
select *
from [table]
where insert_datetime > `2019-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`
```

However, if I use a query to dynamically get the timestamp, it goes back up to 250MB processed:

```
select *
from [table]
where insert_datetime > (select max(insert_datetime) from [other_table])
```

How can I dynamically access a slice of the partitioned table?

Comment: For now, you basically need to run two queries. In the future (please follow [this feature](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36955074)) you'll be able to run one statement to assign the latest partition to a variable, and then have a second query use that variable in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard What do you mean by run two queries?

Comment: Run a query to get the latest date. Then copy/paste the latest date into the next query where you use it in the WHERE clause.